# FancyBox close button shows four buttons in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fancybox

I am using fancybox to allow users to send messages to one another. I have a wierd issue where the fancybox's close button shows four times in google chrome but works just fine in firefox.

[image: Fancybox has 4 close buttons :(]

Here is the css for the button

```
#fancybox-close {
   position: absolute;
   top: -15px;
   right: -15px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background: transparent url('fancybox.png') -40px 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 1103;
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, figured it out! There was a conflicting css in another css file.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmn.. Seeing example page would help.

This shouldnt happen... but im going to throw in a guess that `overflow: hidden;` could help.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

you might want to mess about with the width and height etc too

Comment: Just so you know, that button ( one button image ) is 30x30px.

Comment: Thanks, messed with the css a little and found a conflicting css that was doing it!